# ExchangeWebServices Authentication

Tags: exchangewebservices

We are looking to create a back-end process that will communicate with multiple exchange accounts; creating/updating appointments mainly.

Obviously, we will need to authenticate on the server side when communicating with the Exchange API. We were thinking of creating a single "master" login that has access/rights to all the exchange accounts.

For security reasons, our IT department does not want to supply the "master" login for this use. They, obviously, do not want us to be able to access other's email. Understandable.

Another option we thought of is using each account's separate login credentials to authenticate. Unfortunately, due to our network design, it will not be easy to retrieve this information for each user.

Are there any other options out there? A perfect scenario would be some kind of account/user type in Exchange that cannot read emails but can perform actions.

Any ideas, prior experience, etc is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's right. Using a master login is not acceptable due to security issues.
I also worked in a project similar to this.

Solution is

> impersonation in exchange web services

Search for this topic in the internet. If need some code help please ask. I can give some samples.

Using impersonation we can add appointments,get appointments and update them as so many other things in other accounts which are in our server.

But to use this you have to login to exchange server using admin server account.